# How to inherit the current path when invoking Maven's exec-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven-2, maven

I have an `<exec-maven-plugin>` which calls an external command (in this case, `svnversion`). The command is in the path for the current user.

However, when a separate shell is spawned by the plugin, the path is not initialized. I don't want to hardcode or define a variable for each external command (there would be too much to maintain, especially that there are both Windows and *nix users).

My `pom.xml` contains the following:

```
  <plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.1</version>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <id>svnversion-exec</id>
   <phase>process-resources</phase>
   <goals>
    <goal>exec</goal>
   </goals>
   <configuration>
    <executable>svnversion</executable>
    <arguments>
     <argument><![CDATA[ >version.txt ]]></argument>
    </arguments>
   </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Currently I get the following output:

`[INFO] [exec:exec {execution: svnversion-exec}] 'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

`[ERROR] BUILD ERROR: Result of cmd.exe /X /C "svnversion >version.txt" execution is: '1'.`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's weird because as written in the documentation, the [`executable`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#executable) parameter is not necessarily the full path to an executable:

> The executable. Can be a full path or a the name executable. In the latter case, the executable must be in the PATH for the execution to work.

And on my machine (where `svnversion` is in `/usr/bin/` which is in the `PATH`), the configuration you posted just works (I used the exact same snippet):

```
$ mvn process-resources
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Q2821100
[INFO]    task-segment: [process-resources]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/Q2821100/src/main/resources
[INFO] [exec:exec {execution: svnversion-exec}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed May 12 21:30:35 CEST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/87M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
$ cat version.txt 
exported
```

Maybe double check the `PATH` of the user that is running maven. Also, why do you say that a shell is spawned? Who is spawning that shell?

Comment: Hmm - my comment added yesterday is gone. I was saying that on Windows a new shell (cmd.exe) is spawned by the plugin, this doesn't seem to be happening on Linux.

Comment: @wishihadabettername Ah, wasn't aware of that (I'm under Linux) and I can't find any mention of this, weird. On top of that, I don't get why the spawned shell is not inheriting the environment of the user. Really weird.

Comment: I use windows and no shell pops up for me, everything works just fine

Comment: @seanizer Thanks for confirming this. The OP's issue has to be environment related then.

Answer (score 0):

I read [this](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html):

The plugin will search for the executable in the following order:

- relative to the root of the project
- as toolchain executable
- relative to the working directory (Windows only)
- relative to the directories specified in the system property PATH (Windows Only)

Otherwise use the executable as is.

So "Windows Only" !